# I want to fetch the '_ts' value from cosmosDB as a datetime string in my code to view to the user as to show when the data was recorded

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb

```
          {selectedDate == "aN-aN-NaN" ? (
        <View style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginVertical: 20 }}>
          <WfTextRedItalic>Please Select a date first</WfTextRedItalic>
        </View>
      ) : attendanceRecorded === false && recordedDate !== undefined ? (
        <View style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginVertical: 20 }}>
          <WfTextGreenNormal>
            Attendance was last recorded on {recordedDate}
          </WfTextGreenNormal>
        </View>
      ) : attendanceRecorded === false && recordedDate === undefined ? (
        <View style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginVertical: 20 }}>
          <WfTextYellowItalic>Please Mark Attendance</WfTextYellowItalic>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <View style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginVertical: 20 }}>
          <WfTextGreenNormal>
            Attendance recorded for date {selectedDate}
          </WfTextGreenNormal>
        </View>
      )}
```

As you can see in the above code the 'recordedDate' is what I want to set the value of ts as Im using type script and nodejs

The current items that are fetched or posted from my ClassAttendance Container are :

```
export declare class ClassAttendance {
id: string;
studentId: string;
classProfileId: string;
dateAttended: string;
studentAttended: "Yes" | "No" | "Partial";
teacherId?: string;
lessonId?: string;
startTime?: string;
endTime?: string;
connectionProblem?: boolean;
constructor(studentId: string, classProfileId: string, dateAttended: string, studentAttended?: "Yes" | "No" | "Partial", teacherId?: string, lessonId?: string, startTime?: string, endTime?: string, connectionProblem?: boolean);
```

If any more info is needed please let me know Im new to working with this code

Comment: how are you retrieving this data?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. `_ts` is epoch time (# of seconds since Jan 1, 1970). You can convert that to a date/time object in your code, or via Cosmos DB time/date functions (such as `TimestampToDateTime()`).